# Nginx - Redirect old links

Tags: nginx, configuration, redirect

Let's say that i have thousand of old links that i want to redirect, all old links are like `mydomain.com/1234-article-slug-name` and the new links are  like `mydomain.com/article-slug-name`.

I want to configure my nginx to remove article id from url and redirect to the new url.

I found my solution with apache, but can't figure it out how to achieve it on nginx.

Apache solution:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [0-9]+-
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[0-9]+-(.*)$ $1/$2 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Please try below nginx configuration

`location / {

  if ($request_uri ~ "[0-9]+-"){

    rewrite ^/(.*)/[0-9]+-(.*)$ /$1/$2 redirect;

  }

}`

Comment: @sanjayparmar it worked, make an answer so i can set it as correct :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try below nginx configuration

```
location / {
  if ($request_uri ~ "[0-9]+-"){
    rewrite ^/(.*)/[0-9]+-(.*)$ /$1/$2 redirect;
  }
}
```